# Yielding a dictionary key, value pair in __iter__ method of a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, iterator

I have a super simple class:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, attributes_to_values):
        self.attributes_to_values =  attributes_to_values
```

which I use as follows:

```
attributes_to_values = dict(name='Alex', age=30, happiness=100)
alex = Person(attributes_to_values=attributes_to_values)
```

I want to iterate over `alex` such that I return the keys and corresponding values in `attributes_to_values` attribute.

I've tried inserting the following:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield list(self.attributes_to_values.items())
```

but this doesn't work ...

```
for a, v in alex:
    print(a, v)
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Comment: Why `yield list(...)`? Just `return iter(...)` or `yield from ...`. Otherwise the iterator is only over one value, a list of all the key-value pairs, and it'll only unpack to two values if the dictionary contained exactly two keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an iterable like `item()` you can `yield from` it:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, attributes_to_values):
        self.attributes_to_values =  attributes_to_values

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.attributes_to_values.items()


attributes_to_values = dict(name='Alex', age=30, happiness=100)
alex = Person(attributes_to_values=attributes_to_values)

for a, v in alex:
    print(a, v)
```

**prints**

```
name Alex
age 30
happiness 100
```

Comment: or simply `return iter(self.attributes_to_values.items())`